# Different Webpage on Heroku and Local Host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

So I have my local machine and it is configured to tell me which branch I'm working with on the terminal. It shows me working on the master branch. I then run the command `git push heroku master` and it runs through everything and it tells me that I've deployed to heroku, yet when I go and run `heroku open` it load the default rails page that says "Ruby on Rails: Welcome Aboard" Locally, I see the page I expect to see.

I have removed the default index.html in the public folder and in my routes I have the following: `root :to => 'pages#home'` I've cleared my cache and reset my browser (safari) is there anything else I can do to try to make the webpage show up correctly?

Comment: Are you running rails 3.1 with the new asset pipeline? If so that's one place you can look. People seem to have problems getting the assets updated.

Comment: can you confirm you are making the changes to the master branch and not some other branch in your git repository?

Comment: I ran `git status` and I noticed I hadn't committed the changes to the master branch. Too much late night hacking!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

When checking `$ git status` I realized that git was ignoring my change

`deleted:    public/index.html`

typing `$ git commit -am "comment"` solved it.